# Laravel filled validation rule for array element

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

I need to check input array of strings and raise warning if at least one of array elements is empty.

The following rule is used:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'array',
    'branches.*'       => 'filled|max:255'
    ]);
```

However it seems filled rule doesn't work (while min:1 works fine).
Should it work with array elements or not?

**UPDATE:**
branches array is not mandatory, but if exists it should contain non empty elements.

**UPDATE:**
Finally found mistake in my validation rule.
It should look like

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'array',
    'branches.*.*'       => 'filled|max:255'
    ]);
```

since input array is array of arrays. Now filled rule works as expected with my input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use required instead

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'required|array',
    'branches.*'       => 'required|max:255'
]);
```

From the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules

> **required**
>
> The field under validation must be present in the input data and not
>   empty. A field is considered "empty" if one of the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The value is **null**.
> - The value is an empty string.
> - The value is an empty array or empty **Countable** object.
> - The value is an uploaded file with no path.

---

If you want to validate the array only if there is field data present use `filled`. You can combine this with `present`.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'present|array',
    'branches.*'       => 'filled|max:255'
]);
```

> **filled**
>
> The field under validation must not be empty when it is present.
>
> **present**
>
> The field under validation must be present in the input data but can be empty.

Comment: these fields are not mandatory, but shouldn't be empty if exist in input request.

Comment: @user947668 Is the array itself allowed to be empty? With `'branches.*'       => 'required|max:255'` I'm checking if the fields are empty for each row of the array here.

Comment: @user947668 else use `filled` instead

Answer (score 2):

Considering your comment you should try `nullable`

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'nullable|array',
    'branches.*'       => 'nullable|max:255'
]);
```

**OR**

You can use `present`this will ensure that array should be passed either with values or just an empty array

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'branches'         => 'present|array',
    'branches.*'       => 'nullable|max:255'
]);
```